# Cassandra, partition/primary key: partitioning and constraint

Tags: database-design, cassandra, primary-key, partitioning, nosql

I'm trying to design some column-family in Cassandra but I have some doubt about the primary/partition key.
What I want is the following:

- Spread data evenly around the cluster
- Minimize the number of partitions read

I know that these goals are achievable by choosing the appropriate partition/primary key, but suppose that the partition/primary key choosed allows invalid data in your colum-family, what do you do?

Suppose that I have the following colum-family:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
  groupname text,
  username text,
  PRIMARY KEY (groupname, username))
```

Suppose that a username must belong only in **one group**, with this primary key I can achieve (with some assumption) the previous goals, but there is no way to avoid that a username is placed in more than one group.

Can I simply make assumption on what will be in the column-family or there are ways to avoid the insertion of invalid data?

Comment: It is not possible to create the RDBMS equivalent of a "constraint" in Cassandra.  If you need to ensure invalid data doesn't get written, you'll need to check for that at the application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a table with username as the primary key will ensure only one username-to-group relationship exists:

```
CREATE TABLE group (username text, groupname text, PRIMARY KEY (username));
```

With [lightweight transactions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_ltweight_transaction_t.html) you can prevent updates to a user's group:

```
INSERT INTO group (username, groupname) VALUES ('joe', 'wheel') IF NOT EXISTS;
```

If you wish to query by group, create a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW usersbygroup AS
   SELECT groupname, username FROM group
PRIMARY KEY (groupname, username);
```

Comment: In these day I tried what you told me and it seems to be a good solution, thanks!